# Capistrano private key

Tags: configuration, capistrano, private-key

I have Capistrano installed in my local virtual machine with Linux environment. Also I have a user created in remote server and public/private keys pare generated by PUTTYGEN(private.ppk and id_rsa.pub).

All work fine from windows when I'm trying to connect to the server using password-less method but all will go down if I try to use Capistrano tool, because it will ask me a password from my ssh user which I don't know.

So the only way I can manage with it is make Capistrano to use private kay authentication method.

Could you give an advice to me what I have to change in config of Capistrano to work with private key?

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but have you tried following the directions in the official Capistrano documentation? It says on Windows to use Git Bash: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#ssh-keys-from-workstation-to-servers

Comment: No. Because I don't have this "ssh key" issue in Windows. Running "deploy" command from Windows will print something like curl is not found, or is not a program. Due to that, I can assuming that Capistrano configuration that we use in our project requires Linux. Anyway thank for reply.